# Does a transaction stop all race condition problems in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transactions, race-condition

Consider this situation:

1. Begin transaction
2. Insert 20 records into a table with an auto_increment key
3. Get the first insert id (let's say it's `153`)
4. Update all records in that table where `id >= 153`
5. Commit

**Is step 4 safe?**

That is, if another request comes in almost precisely at the same time, and inserts another 20 records after step 2 above, but before step 4, will there be a race condition?

Comment: Why would you have a separate update step rather than just inserting the correct data in the first place? That's rather weird. You wouldn't need to worry about a "race condition" if you inserted the correct data in the first place. Updating `WHERE id > 153` is also a very strange query. Auto increment ids have no logic to them, and so you should never (as far as I know) be updating solely based on id. And finally, I don't know of any "first insert id" function.

Comment: @ButtleButkus http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id "If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row"

Comment: You are right about LAST_INSERT_ID(), but it doesn't change the fact that the question seems to be about a hypothetical situation that would never exist if basic database structure and procedure are followed. Why would your update criterion ever be the value of a meaningless id? I can't think of any reason. I wouldn't call that a 'race condition' because it's nonsensical. Why would you update immediately after inserting, when you could just insert the correct values to start with? Those are the real reasons this question does not make sense.

Comment: I really can't recall the original problem (almost 3 years ago), but I assume it was necessary. :) Regardless of the reasoning, I believe the basic tenet of the question is legitimate - inside that transaction, could records inserted during an intervening insert be 'seen' and affected by an update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> That is, if another request comes in almost precisely at the same time, and inserts another 20 records after step 2 above, but before step 4, will there be a race condition?

Yes, it will.

Records `21` to `40` will be locked by the transaction `2`.

Transaction `1` will be blocked and wait until transaction `2` commits or rolls back.

If transaction `2` commits, then transaction `1` will update `40` records (including those inserted by transaction `2`)

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying there is a problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be catalogued as a race condition but rather as a DMBS specific behavior. Basically if the DBMS locks the newly inserted records, then the first transaction will not see the records from the second one until the second transaction is committed.

And of course there is the matter of locking the table, if the first transaction write-locks the table then the second one will be blocked on writes until the first one completes. Not sure though if the standard mysql offers this kind of feature. I know MSSQL server it does.